# Visual Studio 2010 RTM is not publishing with ClickOnce

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, clickonce

Is anyone using ClickOnce with VS2010?

I’m getting the following on publish, when the solution builds fine ...

```
Building WindowsFormsApplication1...
Error: Cannot publish because a project failed to build.
```

Have tried everything, new clean project (both windforms and WPF), new temporary key, disabled pre-requisites and played with every publish setting. 
I was hoping it’d be fixed in final, the same thing happened in RC

My 'workaround' at the moment is to use msbuild.exe with a clickonce.proj, along the lines of the following
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/40bb7d32-a9ad-40d7-8113-cb3ed2747e69 
(wired to an external tool+toolbar button as in hanselman's parallel build blog post)

Comment: Do you not get any more error details?  Try turning on more info in the output.  In VS2008 this setting was in `Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run -> MSBuild output verbosity`

Comment: @Yadyn: I tried this with no success.

Comment: Same problem here. Restarting VS2010 solved the problem.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Funnily enough, publish from right-click on the project menu seems to work. It fires up the wizard rather than just publishing, so not ideal, but I do have 2 workarounds now (including the one stated in my original post).

Comment: If you give me the whole error message (the build error in the Errors window), I will ask the ClickOnce product team about this. Also, I assume you have tried deleting the \bin and \obj folders and trying it again?

Comment: I've seen this happen when some of the assemblies are compiled for release and some for debug. Are you publishing as as release? Doe sthis still happen if you do a complete rebuild under Release config, and then publish?

Comment: I have the same issue, there is no other output from either the error list of the output window. Cleaning the solutions makes no difference either

Comment: I can publish from the right click on the project as well but the publish now button gives the same error.

Comment: Robin, 

Yep, tried deleting bin/obj folders - Might be worth you re-reading my posts in detail. Remember this has failed every publish on many different projects, many different machines, many different configurations, many different developers, even projects from scratch. 
As I said, there's no errors on build, and the entire (yes I do mean entire!) error message in the output window follows (nothing in between): 

Building WindowsFormsApplication1...
Error: Cannot publish because a project failed to build.

Comment: Just hit same problem .. Launching from right click works for me also ... thanks very much.

Comment: I can't believe this problem still exists. Thank you for this. Out of the three ways to publish, only the one on the right-click menu works for me in this one particular project. So very annoying.

Answer (score 9):

I have posted a bug on connect so please vote:)

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/572124/failed-to-publish-with-clickonce#tabs

Answer (score 3):

I asked the ClickOnce product lead about this, and he said it is a problem with DevExpress. They offer a solution here: 
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/B156192.aspx

Comment: I don't have CodeRush (or any Devexpress product) and having the same problem (I do have other 3rd party grid, Xceed, though)

Comment: I don't have DevExpress or Xceed and I have this same issue

Comment: Sorry; I don't have an answer for you then. Every other case of this problem has been reported by someone with DevExpress installed.

Answer (score 1):

Little late for this comment, but I found this question because I was experiencing the same thing.  Offering this here because the suggested work-arounds did not work for me.

My project builds and runs without error. I tried a build-clean, manually deleting the projects bin/ and obj/ folders, even using the Publish Wizard/Build-Menu->Publish.  All would fail with the described *"Cannot publish because a project failed to build."*

Here's what made it work for me: 
I'm publishing to a UNC path, but the *Installation Folder URL* (on the project-setting's *Publish* tab,) was set to a URL that's exposed by IIS running on the server that also exposes the UNC path.  I tried just setting the *Installation Folder URL* to the UNC path, and the ClickOnce build finally built and published.  I don't get the web page, but we can live with that for now.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in VS2010.  I was able to publish 24 times without any problems.  The 25th time refused to work, unless I did a right click on the project and published.  I was getting the exact same error with no warnings.  I have all the latest updates and did not change any settings in VS2010.

Comment: I'd be willing to take a look at it if it's something you could share, even in an online meeting. If you're interested, leave a comment on the about page on my blog and I'll e-mail you. http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/about At the very least, I can collect some info and ask the ClickOnce product team about it.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error because my disk was near full. I moved 10GB to another drive, restarted Visual Studio.

The error still occurred if I click "Publish Now", but using Build >> Publish [ProjectName] worked normally.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. Before going to publish your project clean your code which will clean "bin\Debug" folder. Then publish your project and it will run correctly.
Working fine with Visual Studio 2010, 2012, 2013.

Answer (score -3):

I haave been using ClicKOnce successfully with VS2010 for several week.s

This is not a ClickOnce problem, it's a build problem. What is the rest of the error message, i.e. why can't the project build?

Comment: Mr DotNet, 

As I said in my original post, my solution build and runs fine locally - there is no build error when I publish, above is the entire contents of my output window. I've tried with several different solutions, including new & unchanged wpf and winforms solutions, on several different boxes, with several builds of vs 2010 since beta 2. Every relevant clickonce setting & signing option has been tweaked & reset. This is purely a publish problem.

Comment: Do you have DevExpress installed? THis is a known problem. Their recommendation for how to handle it is here: : http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/B156192.aspx